# Is there a way to create a data frame from two vectors to find all of the possible combinations between the vectors? (In r)

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, vector

I have identical two vectors, S and T.

```
S <- seq(from = 0, to = 80, by = 2)
```

T is the exact same. I am trying to create a data frame so that column one would be all of the S values (2 through 80) but column two would be all of the T values (2 through 80). However, I want it so that row one would be 0, 0. Row 2 would be 0, 2. Row 3 would be 0,4. etc. And then row 42 would be 2, 0. I believe it would be possible using a for loop, but I am struggling on how to accomplish this. Any advice would greatly help. I understand that there would be close to if not over 1000 rows, but I feel like there is a simple way to accomplish this.

Comment: I think you are looking for `expand.grid`. There is also `tidyr::expand_grid` and `tidyr::crossing` which is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't label variables `T` or `t` in R. `T` is a popular abbreviation of `TRUE`, and `t` is a function (transpose).

`expand.grid()` is probably what you're looking for.

```
S <- seq(from = 0, to=80, by=2)
TT <- S
expand.grid(S,TT)
```

Yes, it's big.

```
dim(expand.grid(S,TT))
[1] 1681    2
```